# Заданный раздел не найден

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, partition

Есть код с курсором, в который передаются текстовые значения - названия партиций

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
  v_per integer := to_char(to_date('01.08.2018'),'YYYYMM'); 

  cursor d (p1 varchar2, p2 varchar2) is
    select name,
           value
      from t1 partition (p1) tt1 
      join t2 partition (p2) tt2
        on tt1.s_id = tt2.s_id;

  d_row d%rowtype;

begin    

  dbms_output.put_line('P'||v_per||'   :   '||'CD_'||v_per);
  -- Подставляю выведенные значения в запрос - все отрабатывает      
  open d('P'||v_per,'CD_'||v_per);
  fetch d into d_row;
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(d_row.name);
    exit when dwh%notfound;
  end loop;
  close dwh;      
end;
```

При исполнении выходит ошибка что раздел не существует. Однако, когда подставляю сами текстовые значения в запрос - отрабатывает и находит данные. Может я неправильно работаю с партициями в курсоре? Как мне правильно организовать подобный подход?

Comment: А вы подставляете с кавычками или без?

Comment: Без, просто partition (P201808)

Comment: Может как - то можно с динамическим SQL цикл организовать? Сформировать текст запроса и выполнить его в цикле. Тогда я бы просто подставил названия партиций как литеральные значения.

Comment: Когда вы передаете текст, туда подставляется строка `'P201808'`, по этому оракл и не находит раздел

Comment: Судя по названиям партиций у вас нарезка по месяцам. Есть еще нотация, когда можно вместо имени партиции указать значение, которое в нее попадет. Попробуйте его `select * from table PARTITION FOR (date '2016-07-24')`. Возможно работает только в 12

Comment: С такой нотацией стоимость плана выполнения сильно возрастает (( Не подхватывает партиции также как и при указании периода в условии. Но не в этом суть. С помощью динамического SQL никак нельзя цикл организовать?

Comment: Я там добавил ответ, про динамический курсор. Однако с БД или запросом у вас что-то не так, если не подхватывается партиция при явном указании даты или периода в условии.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что что-то не так, но сроки поджимают. За динамик SQL спасибо. Попробую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно открыть курсор для строки, примерно так:

```
declare
  type rc is ref cursor;
  d rc;
....
begin
  open d for 
    'select name,
            value
     from   t1 partition ('||p1||') tt1 
     join   t2 partition ('||p2||') tt2
     on     tt1.s_id = tt2.s_id';
...

end;
```

[docs.oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/openfor_statement.htm#LNPLS01333)

Comment: Конструкция в `open ... for` довольно странная. Вы можете поправить? И по возможности добавите ссылку на [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/openfor_statement.htm#LNPLS01333).